# Preimage of Tensor Product Map

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

If $k$ is a field, $V,V',W,W'$ are $k$-vector spaces, $U\subset W$, $U'\subset W'$ are subspaces, and $f:V \to W$, $g: V' \to W'$ are $k$-linear maps, the equality
$$ f^{-1}(U) \otimes g^{-1}(U')=(f\otimes g)^{-1}(U\otimes U')$$
holds? I feel like it should, as a consequence of flatness (one inclusion is obvious).

Comment: If you take $U=U'=0$, this would imply that $\ker f\otimes\ker g=\ker(f\otimes g)$, which is false.